# Is there a first scratch for Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have two Questinos:
1- Is there any scratch (any text file or so) for the Linux Kernel?
2- If yes, then where can i find it? (I search the net but can't find. Maybe I don't use correct words!)

Thanks alot

**Edit:**
Go to this page: `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-7` the sentence for cite note 4 is as follow: In 1969, Ken Thompson wrote the first UNIX system in assembly language on a PDP-7. Then I look for what he has written!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "scratch"? Who creates it? What do you use it for? What sort of things does it contain?

Comment: do you mean documentation or source code or guides or what? ["Scratch"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+scratch&oq=define+scratch&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i65l2.2367j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) makes no sense in the context you used it

Comment: go to this page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-7
the sentence for cite note 4 is as follow:

In 1969, Ken Thompson wrote the first UNIX system in assembly language on a PDP-7
.
then I look for what he has written!

Comment: @P.A.M: The UNIX system you refer to is "Unics", not a "Linux". Except from basic ideas, these are **completely different Operating Systems**. Please, update your question, its title and tags accordingly.

Comment: How is the quote from Wikipedia page related to your question?

Comment: You've written that remark about the PDP-7 three times so far, but you haven't explained its  relevance. We don't know what you mean by "scratch". Please update your question to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the source files in the kernel Git repository, some thousands of text files, with the millions of lines that compose the Linux kernel. It is a HUGE thing...

Search for 'linux kernel sources'

Comment: go to this page: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-7 the sentence for cite note 4 is as follow: In 1969, Ken Thompson wrote the first UNIX system in assembly language on a PDP-7 . then I look for what he has written!

Comment: @P.A.M You can possibly look at the first commit in the Linux repository, as an approximation of where Linus started. Probably he was developing in a PC running some other OS and using GCC or some other C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If by "scratch" you mean you are searching for the very origins of Linux Kernel, then the answers are:

1) Kind of, sort of yes

2) https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/v0.99/

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: i'm curious - is this the answer you were looking for? what did you mean by "scratch"? maybe it will be a good idea if you edit your question and so it's clear.

Comment: No. it was not the answer but it helped in another way. thanks

Comment: In that case, it would be very helpful if you can clarify *what the heck you are asking* :)